# Erro de compilação PostGreSQL - Erro

Tags: sql, postgresql

Estou tentando rodar essa query em postgresql porém ela dá erro de compilação:

select can.name as 'name' , 
( ( (sco.math 2) + ( sco.specific1 3 ) + ( sco.project_plan * 5 ) ) /10 ) as "avg" 
from candidate can 
join score sco on can.id = sco.candidate_id order by "avg" desc;

O problema está descrito no link abaixo:

https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2738

Comment: qual erro de compilação? de cara já posso dizer que por alias com aspa simples vai dar erro mesmo (em 'name')

Comment: Não sei dizer pois é um problema que estou resolvendo no uri e eu não tenho esse banco instalado no meu pc

Comment: E com "name" também não funcionou :(

Comment: select can.name as 'name' , ... Deve ser "name" com aspas duplas. Não é uma string mas um identificador, vide Quoted identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ta faltando colocar as multiplicações dentro dos parênteses (ex: SCO.MATH 2) . Outra coisa é que no alias não pode colocar aspas simples ( '' ), causa erro.

A query ficaria:

```
SELECT CAN.NAME AS NAME,
   ( ( (SCO.MATH * 2) + ( SCO.SPECIFIC * 3 ) + ( SCO.PROJECT_PLAN * 5 ))/10) AS AVG
FROM CANDIDATE CAN JOIN SCORE SCO ON CAN.ID = SCO.CANDIDATE_ID 
ORDER BY AVG DESC;
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado era esse o problema! Ajudou muito pode crer.